# One source with multiple objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio

One source with multiple objects
I am using MSVS 2010 and I have a C++ source-file which must compile into 2 object-files.
The diiference between those compilations is a "#define UNICODE" for one of them but not for the other. 
I can't (and don't want to) use templates for a this.

Currently ,I use 3 source files for this in my project. 
The actual source is excluded from build ,while the other 2 are wrappers around it.
Like this :

file = wrap-UNICODE.cpp

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include "actual-source.cpp"
// eof
```

file = wrap-ANSI.cpp

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#undef UNICODE
#endif

#include "actual-source.cpp"
// eof
```

When using makefiles i can easily avoid the use of wrapper soucrces ,using different output
switches.
My question is ,I would like to know if (and how) i can do this directly in a MSVS project.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? Sounds like you are going to end up with linker problems, on any platform, unless you have defined different names for UNICODE or !UNICODE. What's inside actual-source.cpp? Can we get a hint?

Comment: Please tag your question as `visual-studio`

Comment: It works ,because of two sets of declarations.

Comment: It also works because of overloading

Comment: Can i re-tag a question (how)

Comment: The contents of the actual source file are a number of values (defines and static variables) and a number functions (all with a LPCTSTR parameter) with the purpose to ease and control Registry access.

Comment: @user517580: I already retagged for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand what you want to do, this is possible.
I have MS Visual Studio 2005 Standard Edition; here is how i can do this (you might have to adjust this if you have a different version, or possibly it might even not work in your version; i hope your computer doesn't explode :) ).

The first step requires manual editing of the project file. Open the project file (it is called `stuff.vcproj` on my machine) and replicate the lines that mention your file:

```
<File
    RelativePath=".\actual-source.cpp"
    >
</File>
<File
    RelativePath=".\actual-source.cpp"
    >
</File>
```

Then, load the project into MSVS. Go to the Solution Explorer (Ctrl+Alt+L on my machine); the project will show two files with identical name. Open the Property Pages of each one (Alt+F7 on my machine) and add any differences you want (e.g. Preprocessor Definitions).

You must also set different names for object files: choose Output Files, Object File Name in the same window (Property Pages), and add different names (e.g. `actual-source-unicode`; MSVS will add the `.obj` extension when compiling). If you don't do that, the two obj-files will have the same name, and one will overwrite the other.

Comment: Sounds like the right thing ! Should be made easier to do ,but if it work it works. At least you fully understood my question. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Edwin: You better write a comment on this in the source file. Per-file properties are confusing as heck for maintenance coders, because MSVC does not display their existence in the IDE (AFAICT). Someone might come across the duplicate file entry, and decide to delete the (perceived) duplicate.

Comment: @DevSolar: You're right about that this can be confusing. But the source is well documented (for myself) and it's a personal project. And someone who thinks he is smart and decides to delete something without consulting others ,should be shot on sight (joke).

Comment: @Edwin: You see, I've worked the last 10 years with code of other people who are no longer available for consultation. It happens, even for private projects. That's why I was just sayin'.

Comment: @DevSolar: You're absolutely right. I've been there too. One of most annoying thing about other people programming is the lack of proper documentation in sources.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can create multiple builds in your solution. Just go in the configuration manager of the solution (should be accessible from contextual menu on the solution).

In this way you can also avoid to have two versions of your file. It is sufficient to set the define options differently in the two configurations.

Comment: This not exactly what i want to do. I need to do the very same thing in 1 application once in the UNICODE way and once in thr ANSI way, and then compare differences.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio defines _UNICODE for you if you intend to build unicode apps.

Comment: I know that. I use that already ! I want do UNICODE and ANSI the same time

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use different configurations for your two builds (as Luca Martini mentions) and then use Batch Build? You can then compare the compiled outputs any way you want.

Comment: i don't want to compare the output of the compilations.

Comment: It is not programmatic problem. I just want to get rid of the wrapper sources without using two buids because it not necessay. Using a make file i create 2 object-files from 1 source code by having 2 build clauses where i just change the output file and a definition of a symbol.